# How to modify or insert StopStartDate field?

Tags: case, fields, casemilestone

I have to migrate some tickets from other system to Salesforce.
Some cases are waiting for requester response and milestones for them should be stopped.
Using Data Loader I can insert case with properly set `IsStopped` field. But looks like I cannot insert value for `StopStartDate` field.
I also noticed, then `StopStartDate` field by default will be set to time, when case was inserted using Data Loader.

Is there any other way to set proper date for `StopStartDate` field? And to edit it for already inserted cases?

Comment: ['Case.StopStartDate'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) doesn't have the Create or Update property. The description is "The date and time an entitlement process was stopped on the case.". Can you find the related [Entitlement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_entitlement.htm)?

Comment: Yes, I can find related Entitlement.

Comment: And can you "stop" that Entitlement? I assume this is the `EndDate` field.

Comment: But if I stop Entitlement, then it will affect all cases with this Entitlement assigned. And I want to have it assigned only for one/few particular cases.

Comment: Also setting `EndDate` to past does not allow me to edit `StopStartDate` on case level. It only makes not completed m'stones are not visible anymore.  When Entitlement is active again, m'stones are back, but target times are same.  
  
Additionally I contacted Salesforce. They said that it's **not possible** to modify existing `StopStartDate` value or to insert proper value via Data Loader. But I'm not sure if they understood me correctly :-)

Comment: I suspect support are correct then. You can't specify the `StopStartDate`. You might be able to fake something for testing using JSON deserialization, but that isn't going to help you with actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response from Salesforce Support and your findings with trying to update the related Entitlement records I'm going to conclude that this isn't currently possible.

Consider creating an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?keywords=Entitlement) and linking to it from here.